# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN when trying to acess page from a local server

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, linux-networking, database-connection

I'm working in a company where we use a local server in linux to store some data, particularly our BugZilla, Wiki and a subversion repository. The server is accessed both locally from the development room and from other parts of the company.

Yesterday one of the local users started having problems connecting to the server by ssh using the command `ssh -X user@servdes`, where `servdes` is the server name (from Linux Terminal). The problem was temporarily solved by replacing the server name with its IP while my machine was still able to connect to it fully.

Today the problem got worst: although I'm still able to access some part of the server (from inside Ubuntu's Nautilus), I'm unable to acess BugZilla, the wiki and the repository by any means. Trying to open both BugZilla and the Wiki from inside Chromium I get the error message `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`.

I did some research on Google on how to solve this problem but most of the help is with Windows only solutions, so useless. I changed the DNS server of the server and did a reload on its cache, but I got no results. I'm beginning to think this might be a problem in the Internet router, but I want to avoid resetting it for now.

Any suggestions on how could I possibly solve this problem? Useful to notice no one touched in the server for some time apart from the normal use (file changes and usage of BugZilla and the like).

Comment: `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` means that the DNS record was not present on the authoritative DNS server when the device attempted to look it up. You will need to refer this problem to your IT staff who manage the DNS systems. We cannot assist you with troubleshooting it.

Comment: It sounds like the internal DNS name for 'servdes' is not working.  Can you ping or dig that host?

Comment: @jmreicha no, I can only ping the IP address. BTW I managed to surpass the problem by using the IP directly.

Comment: @Momergil Definitely check DNS then to see what happened to the record.